# What's the formula to calculate the value of a cell based on the row number

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to Google Sheets.

I'm looking for a way to make this happen:

I have file in this format:

```
number    name
```

If `number` starts from 100, for example, how can I make each cell in `number` increase for each nth row by 20?

In other words, in the second row number will be (20*2)+100, and in the third row it will be (20*3)+100, and so on.

So the results will look something like:

```
number    name
100       John Smith
120       Jane Doe
140       George Washington
```

Comment: It's rather unclear what you're after here. What have you already tried? Can you [edit] your question to include some sample data and what the expected outcome is? Include the code you would use to do this in Python; that may help someone craft an answer.

Comment: thanks look above to see my edit to question

Comment: It seems English isn't your first language. I've made an attempt to clean up your question. Please edit it if something isn't right. I took out the part about doing something in Python, as that's programming, and that's off-topic here. You'd do well to take the [tour] and also look over the advice at [ask].

Comment: thanks for helping me you just made something wrong the value of number cell start from 100 to 120 to 140 etc so every row increase by 20 and i edited that

Comment: I suspected as much.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want the number to increment by 20 on each row. Assuming "number" is in column A, couldn't you just do this?

```
      A       B
1  number   name
2    100
3  =A2+20
4  =A3+20
5  =A4+20
```

That results in:

```
      A       B
1  number   name
2    100
3    120
4    140
5    160
```

Comment: thanks for respond but i have 1000 row and the idea of doing that for manually terrified me and it must be a formula for doing that in program like google spreadsheet

Comment: You can simply autofill the column. I autofill a thousand rows all the time.

Answer (score 0):

`ROW()` is the Google Sheets built-in function that returns the row number of the cell that holds the formula.

To use a single formula to return the row number for 1000 rows we coulde use something like the following

```
=ArrayFormula(ROW(A2:A1001)-1)
```

The -1 makes the automatic row numbering to start on 1 instead of 2

To apply the above to the OP case we could use the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(100 + (ROW(A2:A1001)-1)*20))
```